# grub unable to add windows to boot menu

Tags: windows-10, boot, linux-mint, grub2

### Problem:

unable to add win 10 to grub2 menu and can't boot to win 10 directly either.

### Setup:

5 disks:

- samsung 250GB ssd for win10
- kingston 120GB ssd for Linux Mint
- intel 180GB ssd as fast storage (only used in win10)
- 2 random hdd's (1TB and 2TB  mainly used by win10)

currently inside Linux mint because of win 10 won't boot.

### History:

set up pc with win 10 at first.
decided to dual-boot with mint on separate ssd (Kingston 120GB).
Did something dumb and placed grub on the main ssd with windows (Samsung 250GB).
managed to add win 10 to that grub installation.
everything was fine and I booted whatever os i wanted via grub on main ssd.

later:
messed up mint and had to format and install a new version on that ssd (Kingston 120).
Grub got messed up and had to use boot-repair from live boot for mint to fix it. (grub then got installed on Kingston 120GB ssd instead)
Now windows won't be detected.

### What I have tried

- running boot-repair again
- boot win 10 install usb
- update-grub

boot-repair said I should include this if i whent to a forum for help...

[ubuntu pasebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KwwFMqxY7m/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution:

- Download and run GRUB CUSTOMIZER
- Add windows to grub menu with cainload mode.
- Restart and push `Esc`rapidly to enter menu
- Select windows and press enter